# php strtotime funtion is not giving output

Tags: php, date, yii2, comparison, strtotime

I am using strtotime() function to compare two dates, one is today and second from DB, It was working fine some days ago but today its not working
Here is the code

```
$today=strtotime(date("d-M-Y H:i A"));
$registration_start_date=strtotime($model->registration_start_date);
```

in this code there is no output for $today even I have tried to echo just date and date was printed out but when I kept date("d-M-Y H:i A") in strtotime its empty, even $registration_start_date=strtotime($model->registration_start_date); is giving proper output.
kindly help out.
Thanks

Comment: I tried this code and it works fine for me

<?php
  $today=strtotime(date("d-M-Y H:i A"));
  echo $today;
?>

Comment: I tried A from date format then it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens with date now:

```
php > echo date("d-M-Y H:i A");
30-Jun-2020 17:29 PM
```

17:29 PM?

Just remove A from date format, you use H - this is already 24 hour format:

```
php > var_dump(strtotime(date("d-M-Y H:i A")));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(strtotime(date("d-M-Y H:i")));
int(1593531060)
```

Maybe this code works before noon but i wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Thanks I already tried this as you described amd it worked...  Thanks for your help...